# Escaping field html within javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/LRFMQ/14/

I tried to add two select fields to each line when hitting the add question button, so the added questions have the same fields as the initial one.

This is the problem bit of the code:

```
<select>
    <option value="single">Single line reply</option>
    <option value="multi">Paragraph reply</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="single">Required</option>
    <option value="multi">Optional</option>
</select>
```

It doesnt seem to like the way I have added my html form code into the javascript. Do I need to escape it somehow?

Comment: have you visted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: There's no need to make appended or dynamic html look tidy.  Just add it as a string, with no indentation (or put a single \ at the end of each line of unterminated text : http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/LRFMQ/17/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9kGy6/, Just used string concatenation properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden `div` for structure and `.clone` it for adding.

```
$("div.toClone").clone().removeClass("toClone").insertBefore(InputsWrapper);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LRFMQ/18/)